# How can I check whether a node exists in an XML file?

Tags: xml

How can I check whether a node exists in an XML file, and also count the number of nodes?

I have one XML file for an example:

```
 <Employee>
  <Emp>
    <Name id="1">   A     </Name>
    <Name id="2">   C     </Name>
    <Name id="3">   D     </Name>
   </Emp>
  </Employee>
```

Comment: What programming language do you want the solution in? Unless you specify that, someone will vote a negative for this question as it is incomplete.

Answer (score 6):

With linq 2 xml in c#:

```
var employee = XElement.Load(someStream);
var emp = employee.Element("Emp");
if( emp != null )
{
   int count = emp.Elements("Name").Count();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using XSL to transform this document then I would assume that a variable would give the best functionality.  You'd use this:

```
<xsl:variable name="Name_Count" select="count(//Name)"/>
```

This will give you the number of nodes of `Name` and you can change that to anything you'd like.  Obviously if it's zero then there are none, otherwise it's the count.

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

_xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));

XmlNode _node = _xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Employee/Emp");

if (_node != null)

{

    XmlNodeList _nodeList = _node.SelectNodes("Name");

    Response.Write(_nodeList.Count);
}

else

{

    Response.Write("Emp node doesnot exist");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming in Java there are two related libraries you should look at.

JDOM - http://www.jdom.org/
DOM4J - http://www.dom4j.org/

I'd look at Dom4j 2.0 now since it's got support for generics, XPath, and now has some better high level support. Dom4j I think was forked from the earlier jdom.

In either you can read XML from a file, URL, string etc, parse it and check for nodes
in only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is great. But just in case you are stuck on a system with .NET 2.x you might have to do it the "old" (XPath) way (where xmlFragment is your string of XML above):

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xmlFragment));
XPathNavigator n = doc.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//Name[@id='4']");
if(n==null){//Node does not exist}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 4 nodes here, assuming that your `</Emp>` is matched by an opening `<Emp>` tag:  `<Emp>`, `<Name>`, `ID`, and the string `"   D     "` would all be represented as nodes. It's not clear from your question whether you really would want to count **all** of these.  I'm also not sure whether you want to determine the existence of a specific one of them.

Ultimately, though, XPath is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to XPath, many languages that have XML DOM support will allow you to call a method on an XML Document like:

```
GetAllNodesWithTagName(string tagname);
```

Your code to see if it exists would look something like this (written in pseudocode):

```
int num_nodes = 0;
string node_name = "Name"; // want to find all of the <Name> tags
XMLNode [] nodes = GetNodesWithTagName(node_name);
num_nodes = nodes.Length;
```

XPath is good, but it's better suited for easily navigating an XML document in interesting and complex ways. This code will be a bit more straightforward than the corresponding XPath code.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName["tagname"]` is also a DOM method which can be used to get a node. If the node does not match, method with return null.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nNodeExistCount = xmlOuput.GetElementsByTagName("NodeName").Count;

if (nNodeExistCount>0)
{
    Response.write(" The NodeName exists!");
}
else
{
    Response.write(" The NodeName does not exist!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT transformation just trythis:

> < xsl:choose>
>
> < xsl:when test="//Employee/Emp">
>
> < -- Node exists-->
>
> < /xsl:when>
>
> < xsl:otherwise>
>
> < --Node does not exist-->
>
> < /xsl:otherwise>
>
> < /xsl:choose>