# How to find child dynamically inside XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

how to check whether child node is there for the product node in the following xml:

```
   <product>
        <SysSectionName>Processors</SysSectionName>
        <section>
          <subsection>
            <SysSectionName>CPU#1</SysSectionName>
          </subsection>
       </section>
  </product>
```

I have tried this:

```
foreach (XmlNode xn1 in sectionNode)
{
  XmlNode node = xn1.FirstChild; 
  if (xn1.HasChildNodes)
  {
     //do something..
  }     
}
```

Comment: Please have a look **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653014/how-can-i-check-whether-a-node-exists-in-an-xml-file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlNodeList snode = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/product/section/subsection");
foreach (XmlNode xn2 in snode)
{
    //it comes inside if there will be a child node.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this piece of code to get the product nodes from XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("Your Xml String");

var products = doc.Descendants("product");

foreach (var product in products)
{
    //... do something ...
}
```

Comment: `XmlDocument` is oldschool. All the cool kids use `XDocument`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to find whether product node has any child node?
If yes,

```
XmlNodeList productNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Product");
foreach(XmlNode pNode in productNodes)
{
  if(pNode.ChildNodes.count >0)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think XLinq (Linq for Xml) is what you're looking for.
Then you should load the Xml using XDocument, and for any XElement you have the "Descendants()" method, which returns list of child XElements. If there are no child elements, the list will have no elements as well.